# jQuery not working on application.html.erb page in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to trigger an event on click with some jQuery that's just in `<script>` tags in my application.html.erb file, but nothing is happening. 
My entire application.html.erb file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>


 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ab1ae4c50b.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.0.0/ekko-lightbox.css"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy|Quattrocento|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
      console.log("yo");
       $('.nav li').removeClass();
       $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');

 });
</script>
</head>
 <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default homenav">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>

     </div><!--navbar-header-->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-det">
        <li><%=link_to '<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>home'.html_safe, root_path%></a>
       <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria- hidden="true"></i><br>go'.html_safe, page_path('location') %></li>
         <li><%=link_to '<i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i>    <br>stay'.html_safe, page_path('hotels') %></li>
         <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>play'.html_safe, page_path('game'), {:class=>"thing"} %></li>
        <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>the big day'.html_safe, page_path('info') %></li>
       <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Davey/Leesy'.html_safe, page_path('about') %></li>
       <li><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>registry'.html_safe, page_path('registry') %></li>
        <li><%= link_to  '<i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>rsvp'.html_safe, '/login' %></li>

    </ul>
  </div><!--collapse-->

</div><!--container-->
 </nav>


 <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Oddly, when I try `$(document).load(function(){` instead of a click event, I will get my console log. I cannot figure out why my click event won't work, though! I've removed turbolinks from the header and from my Gemfile, My application.js file is:

```
   // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js,  which will include all the files
  // listed below.
  //
  // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
  // or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
  //
  // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
  // compiled file.
  // 
  // Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets- directives) for details
  // about supported directives.
 //
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs


//= require_tree .
```

Am I missing sprockets?

I also have jQuery in script tags on other views, and that's working fine--it's just not working on this one. Interestingly, when I also try to modify these li's with CSS, nothing I do changes them--it's like I can't access them via CSS either!

Comment: Can you post your whole `application.html.erb` and `application.js` manifest file? Have you removed require turbolinks from the manifest too? You can check if it's a turbolink-still-in-action issue changing `$(document).ready(function(){` to `$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {` and check if it works.

Comment: Did you try looking at the browser console? You could instead change this to a delegated event handler with `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){ /* ... */ });`. You don't need to wait for document ready in this case, and it will work across turbolinks visits.

Comment: @max that didn't change anything for me.

Comment: @mrlew I updated my question to include my entire application.html.erb and my manifest js

Answer (score 0):

Try to write below code in body tag instead of head tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
      console.log("yo");
       $('.nav li').removeClass();
       $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');

 });
</script>
```

Comment: that didn't change anything, either.

Comment: try to add click function under document.ready function like

    $(document).ready(function(){
      //add click function
    })

Comment: still nothing. Interestingly, I also tried to modify these list items with CSS, and can't access them via CSS either!

Comment: correct your below code:

<li><%=link_to '<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>home'.html_safe, root_path%></a>

add </li> instead of </a>

Try to add alert under  click function.
What you are trying to do under click function, you add removeClass but not mention which class to remove.Check code:
$('.nav li').removeClass();

Also you add active class in href???
check it:
$($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');